# apache rule to transform x-storage-url to X-Storage-Url

Tags: apache, http-headers, httpresponse, jclouds, mod-headers

We are looking for a Apache rule to transform x-storage-url to X-Storage-Url in the http response header.

alternatively to *add* (if that's possible) an "X-Storage-Url" header whenever you find an "x-storage-url" header and use the same header value.

Any http ninja who can help us with this?
this is related to jClouds issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-155

http://www.mail-archive.com/user@jclouds.incubator.apache.org/msg00159.html

Comment: This is almost certainly a bad idea. Attaching meaning to header field casing isn't just inconvenient, it's *incorrect.* [RFC 2616 Sec 4.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) explicitly states that `Field names are case-insensitive.`

Comment: i understand, however this is a bug in the jClouds library, that we are trying to work around......

Answer (score 0):

jclouds 1.6.2 and 1.7.0 include a fix for this; see [JCLOUDS-155](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-155).